# Get value of angular to localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I want to get the value of **angular** and store it in my **local storage**. something like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" value="{{sudent.id}}">

<script>
  localStorage.setItem("STUDID", document.getElementById("ID").value);
</script>
```

and I want the result to be:

```js
<script>
  localStorage.setItem("STUDID", "HUMMS-201906");
</script>
```

Comment: use `ng-model` for `input` element and in the controller access input value using `$scope`.

Comment: The `ngModel` directive provides the two-way data-binding by synchronizing the model to the view, as well as view to the model. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#simple-form).

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-model` so as to provide two-way data binding and in controller access the ng-model value using `$scope`.

```js
angular.module('inputExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.student = {
      "id": 101
    };

    console.log($scope.student.id);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="inputExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" name="studentId" ng-model="student.id" required>
  </div>
</body>
```